# openssl AES256 multiple encryption of file parts (join later)

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, encryption-symmetric

For partial file upload and encryption i'd like to read chunks (example: 10MB) from a large file (example: 100MB), encrypt the chunk with AES256 and upload the chunk to the server.
On the server the chunks are joined together to one big file (which then should represent the complete encrypted file).

I'd like to avoid a full encryption of the file (example: 100MB!) before taking out chunks and sending them to the server (CPU overhead, because i would then first need to copy the whole file and do AES256 over the whole file).

I tried the following (example for a 16MB File = 2 Chunks = 1*10MB + 1*6MB)

1st chunk is ~10MB, ensured then the chunksize is a multiple of 16 (AES_BLOCK_SIZE)

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX e_ctx;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&e_ctx);
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&e_ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
EVP_EncryptUpdate(&e_ctx, enc_data, &outlen, unenc_data, chunksize_to_load_from_file_unencrypted);
```

During the 1st chunk, i do not call EVP_EncryptFinal_ex() because the encryption is not finished yet (maybe this is the problem?).

2nd chunk is ~6MB, there i encrypt the rest of the data offset from `&outlen` above

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX e_ctx;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&e_ctx);
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&e_ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
EVP_EncryptUpdate(&e_ctx, enc_data, &outlen, unenc_data, chunksize_to_load_from_file_unencrypted);
EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&e_ctx, enc_data+outlen, &final_length);
```

On the server the two file-parts get's joined.
I then can decrypt the file "successfully", same size of the unencrypted file. But at offset ~10MB, some bytes are different (16 Bytes! = `AES_BLOCK_SIZE`)

Any idea? Could that be the padding? Is that not only at the end?
Does `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex` act different when not pass through the whole file through `EVP_EncryptUpdate`?

How can i do transmission of encrypted partial-file-chunk and join them on the server to get a proper encrypted file?

Thanks!

Comment: What's 100MB in the current day and age? That may encrypt in a second!

Comment: 100MB is a example, could also be up to <=2GB. I'm coding a background sync daemon, where AES256 encryption might take some important CPU ticks which the user won't like....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong initialization vector for the second chunk.  With [CBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29), the `iv` of the subsequent encryption should be the last 16 bytes of the previous ciphertext.  That way, just concatenating the encrypted parts gives the encryption of the whole.

Comment: Will test this out. Was creating my IV with EVP_BytesToKey, maybe the IV get's randomized?!

Comment: Any way of generating the initial `iv` will work (although to be secure, it should be generated at random).  The `iv` is only for the first block, though.  The `iv` for subsequent blocks is just the ciphertext from the previous block.  See the CBC link for a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use counter mode encryption for this, but that seems unavailable for OpenSSL. With OpenSSL block ciphers you cannot just start encrypting/decrypting in the middle of the file. For CBC you need to know the previous encrypted block and insert that as the IV. If you encrypt them sequentially at the client you can then relatively easily decrypt them at the server.

Of course you may also encrypt each block separately and then concatenate the decrypted blocks together.